# Display and label a stack of Sentinel 1 images with the date

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1, for-loop

I have a stack of Sentinel 1 images and I want to display all of them one by one and want the label to be the date of corresponding image. I am trying a for loop for that but I am unable to visualize the results.

Link :https://code.earthengine.google.com/e58e28ed2fd14cc2b8cbaf4ef666b5bb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ee.Image.get()` option to retrieve the specific property of interest (in your case it is `system:time_start` which corresponds to the date of acquisition.)

The new loop should look something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i <=2; i++)
{
  var image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(i));
  var label = ee.Date(image.get("system:time_start")).format('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').getInfo();
  Map.addLayer(image,vis_params2,label,true)
}
```

Explanation:

1. `ee.Date()` function converts the acquisition times from milliseconds to date-time object.
2. I have used the `.format()` option to convert the `ee.Date` object
   to a string but you can use any other method too.
3. The `.getInfo()` is important because Map.addLayer() is a client-side function. So the label property to be passed needs to be retrieved from server-side to client-side.

[Link to corrected code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b7996afc877a861655d2fa1ecea90ffc)

Comment: Works perfectly. Thankyou so much :) 
I had no idea about client side function. I shall look for it now. 

A follow-up query: I defined a variable in the for loop condition and the code stopped working. I am wondering what could be the problem (Line 19) Link: 
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e4bf667ba4cb028613020989c80e7795

Comment: the `for` loop runs on the client-side. Its arguments must be retrieved to the client-side first before running the loop. `iff` variable resides in the server-side. To retrieve it use `.getInfo()`. So use `for (var i=0; i <=iff.getInfo()-1; i++)`. If you want to read more about server-side and client-side, checkout this link: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server.

Comment: Thankyou so much @kkrao. worked perfectly :)